# spring mvc encoding messy code when get value from the post request

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, encoding, http-post

I use spring mvc to develop a web site. I have put accept-charset="UTF-8" in the form attribute and

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

in the web.xml. But still, I get the messy code when saving an entity into the database. I have searched and  found the solution is always be the  characterEncodingFilter in the web.xml, which I have already done. Can somebody help understand this problem?

Comment: Provided the encoding is set correctly, you should receive clean decoded data in ServletRequest.getParameter() and this should already be handled at the servlet-container level (well below Spring data-binding). Can you supply an example, indicating what inputs & results you're seeing & what you expect?

Comment: maybe your database or table is not configured for UTF-8?

Comment: Or the database connection is not set to UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly solution to my problem.